# Overwrite File With Cron Job OR Multiple Entry Cron?

Tags: php, apache, cron

I have the following cron job

```
0   0 * * * /usr/bin/wget http://www.example.com/chron_sitemap.php
```

This basically runs the script to create a new sitemap located at sitemap.xml

The problem arises because the sitemap already exists and it needs to be either overwritten or deleted before it is created.

I tried

```
unlink('sitemap.xml');
```

but that erases the file and even though it's at the top of the script, and I have at the bottom

```
$xml->save("http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml");
```

It doesn't work. I still get a 404 - page not found.

I also thought about putting in another cron job to delete said file, but that could possibly leave a gap between deletion and creation.

What's the best way to proceed here and how?

THANK YOU!

PS: I'm using cPanel to set chrons if that makes a difference.

Comment: Use a local filesystem path (`dirname(__FILE__) . '/sitemap.xml'`) to save the file.

Comment: @DCoder Thanks - Sorry :) updated spelling. Saving the file works just fine if I take out unlink('sitemap.xml') ... As soon as I add it, it doesn't anymore. So it does create the file in the proper place - problem is if I delete it and then recreate it within same script, it doesn't work. I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command will not work

```
$xml->save("http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml");
```

better use

```
$xml->save("local path to file") //e.g $xml->save("/var/www/sitemap.xml");
```

to actually store it on you local machine.

http://www.php.net/manual/de/domdocument.savexml.php